# plotly displaying pandas dataframe on a radial chart

Tags: pandas, plotly-python

Thank you for taking the time to read my likely silly question.

I have time series data in a pandas dataframe and would like to plot two separate financial years as two separate lines, with the month as theta and the number of queries received each month as r.

```
df['FY'] = np.where(df['call_DT'] < "01/04/2020", "Financial Year 1", "Financial Year 2")
df['Month'] = df['call_DT'].dt.month

df = df.sort_values('Month')
df = df.groupby('Month')
df = df['Count of queries'].sum().reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Month')

fig = px.line_polar(df,r="Count of queries",theta=df.index)
plot(fig)
```

I understand I am removing all rows other than 'Count of queries', I am not sure how I am doing this, so I understand why the color would not show.

However, with r = "Count of queries" and theta = "Month", no graph is displayed. I understand I have butchered this by not properly understanding the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

A snippet of the used columns for this task. I group the data by month and sum the count of queries column. I want to differentiate the two lines in the radial chart by financial year, rather than year, so I included the 'B/A' column to differentiate between them.

```html
    call_DT               B/A  Count of queries
2  2021-05-17  Financial Year 2                 1
5  2021-05-17  Financial Year 2                 1
16 2021-05-14  Financial Year 2                 1
18 2021-05-14  Financial Year 2                 1
26 2021-05-14  Financial Year 2                 1
```

Comment: If you could post an snippet of your dataframe, it would be very helpful to be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Pascalco, I included the snippet in the edit. Thanks for the response